# Seprate package.json for front end and back end in Laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel application. Currently there's a single package.json file in the root of the project that has scripts to build the frontend app.js and app.css as well as backend.

Can I use two different ones that would be in frontend/package.json and backend/package.json so that front-end has only front end related packages and scripts while the backend has only backend related packages and scripts.

Thoughts?

Comment: You may try this too.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471757/one-project-with-multiple-package-json-files

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel5, we have `laravel-mix` that can help you do that easily. In the root directory of your project, there is a file known as `webpack.mix.js`, and in it by default there are the following:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

If you want to have separate js and scss files, just add here. Say you want to add `theme.js` and `theme.scss` for the frontend, just include as follows:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/js/theme.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/sass/theme.scss', 'public/css');
```

Of course don't forget to add the corresponding files inside the `resources/js` (changed from laravel 5.5 onwards) and `resources/sass` respectively.