# NPM install with different package.json

Tags: node.js, frontend, npm-install

Can you have two different package.json files in same path?
(file names: package1.json and package2.json)

If so, how can you run *npm install* referring different package.json files from same path? Looking to execute one json file at a time.

FYI: newbee to NPM

Comment: What is the reason for having multiple package.json files? You could setup your project with subfolders as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/q/50471757/8678978

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal way to it. You should change the structure of your project.

Nevertheless, one way to do this in *nix systems is

```sh
cp package1.json package.json && npm install && rm -rf package.json
```

If you already have a `package.json` file, then

```sh
cp package.json temp.json && cp package1.json package.json && npm install && rm -rf package.json && cp temp.json package.json && rm -rf temp.json
```