# Individual package-lock.json for npm workspaces

Tags: npm, npm-workspaces

I have two packages inside my npm workspace `api` & `cdk`. I would like to create an individual `package-lock.json` inside `api` & `cdk` as both of those projects will get deployed individually. Is this currently possible with npm workspaces? What are other alternatives or strategies?

```
├── api
│    ├── package.json
├── cdk
│   ├── package.json
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
```

Comment: Kindly have a look on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471757/one-project-with-multiple-package-json-files

Answer (score 1):

No, a package-lock.json file will not be generated during npm install for workspaces. This is because workspaces allow for mutual dependencies to be shared.

To handle your CI/CD process, you should use the root package-lock.json and package.json files for each workspace.

Personally, I would suggest creating a root builder Dockerfile that installs all the dependencies. Each workspace's Dockerfile can then copy the dependencies from the root builder.